# Transferring MySQL Data from Different Tables to a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$login = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$db = 'database';
$filename = 'output.csv';
$table = 'table';

mysql_connect($server, $login, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");

// fetch a row and write the column names out to the file
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

// remove the result pointer back to the start
mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

// and loop through the actual data
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

I am trying to import data from a Joomla website to a CSV file. Using Joomla extensions create so many database tables and it's making my situation more complicated.

I have tried the code above and it gave me my desired initial result of creating a CSV file with data from one database table. Now, What I am trying to figure out is how to create the same file; but I am getting data from different but related tables.

Here's the situation:

- Table 1 contains an ID that can be traced by Table 2, 3.
- Some of the fields are not needed, there are only selected fields to be exported.

How will I do this?

```
$table1 = 'database_table1';
$table2 = 'database_table2';
$table3 = 'database_table3';
$table4 = 'database_table4';

$res = mysql_query("SELECT table1_field1, table1_field2 FROM $table1 t1
    INNER JOIN $table3 t3 table2_field1, table2_field2, table2_field3, table2_field4 ON t1.id = t3.pid
    INNER JOIN $table2 t2 table3_field1, table3_field2, table3_field3, table3_field4, table3_field5 ON t1.id = t2.content_id
    INNER JOIN $table4 t4 table4_field1, table4_field2 ON t3.id = t4.review_id
");
```

Comment: What you're saying is that each of the tables has different fields, and you're not sure how to dynamically approach that hurdle?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, What I am trying to achieve is.. Instead of the `"SELECT * FROM"` a single database table, I want to get my needed data from four different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your sql statement from:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
```

to something like

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT t1.title, t1.introtext,t2.jr_street, t2.jr_city, t2.jr_state, t2.jr_postalcode, t2.jr_country,t3.created, t3.name, t3.title, t3.comments, t4.rating_sum, t4.ratings_qty   FROM $table1 t1
                    INNER JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.content_id
                    INNER JOIN $table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.pid
                    INNER JOIN $table4 t4  ON t1.id = t4.review_id
");
```

Make sure ids are mapping correctly.

Comment: Are `t1` `t2` and `t3` database tables? Why is that `FROM $table t1`?

Comment: Those are alias for tables. We need to mention table alias next to it like `$table t1`. Also, make sure to add lines like `$table = 'table';` in the start of the script.

Comment: Please see my edited question. The code at the bottom is the one that I tried. I am getting errors with my query. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Are you sure that we will be getting all of the data `FROM $table1 t1` (on the first part of the query).

Comment: These are just warning, there is issue in mysql statement. Join the tables appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean "Join the tables appropriately"? `INNER JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.content_id` Do I need to fix this line?

Comment: Oh. I forgot to include in my question. Not all rows from the table 2 contains the id that is equal to the row of the table 1. Do you think this is the reason why I am getting the warnings?